# Keeping Service and App code separate

Tags: android, service

I'm developing an App and a Service on Android.  Currently the source code for both are in the same project, but I'd like to separate the two so that I don't accidentally call App code from the Service.  That is, the App should depend on the Service, but never the other way around.  My goals are two fold:

1) Prevent incorrect/confusing/damaging code intermingling.  The Service should not do UI (App) things and the UI (App) should not do Service things (e.g. talking to the remote server, handling and storing data).

2) Make it easier to share the Service between different Apps in the future.

I'd prefer not to have two separate APKs to install, as that makes maintenance more complicated.

I've done some searching and looking but couldn't find a description of the correct/best way to do this.  Thank you.

Comment: Extract service and related code into separate "android-library" module and have your app module depend on it.

Comment: @Pawel if you'll make that an answer, I'll mark it as correct.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pawel stated in a comment, I factored my service code into an "Android Library" module.  This is done under File => New => New Module => Android Library.  I then refactored all the service code into the module.  After that, I made sure my app depended on the module.